# getting null pointer exception when mocking the objects using mockito

Tags: soap, junit, gradle, mockito, spring-integration

I am working spring boot, spring integration, gradle project. And I am using junit and Mockito for mocking my soap service. And Basically I have these three classes for my application.
Junit Class for mocking soap service.

```
 @Before
public void setup() {
    gw=Mockito.mock(ProjectGateway.class);
    pc=new ProjectController();
    pc.setGateWay(gw);
}

@Test
public void testGetProject() throws Exception {
    GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects mockRequest=new GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects();
    GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjectsResponse mockResponse=getMockResponse();
    when(gw.getResponse(mockRequest)).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    List<Project> projects=pc.getProject();
    assertEquals(1,projects.size());
}`
```

and an interface which calls soap service.

```
`public interface ProjectGateway {

public GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjectsResponse getResponse(
        GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects request);
```

}'

and the method on which I need to do unit testing.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Project> getProject() {
    GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects request = new GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects();
    GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjectsResponse response = gw
            .getResponse(request);
    JAXBElement<ArrayOfProjectContainer> arr = response
            .getGetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjectsResult();
    ArrayOfProjectContainer arr1 = arr.getValue();
    List<ProjectContainer> arr2 = arr1.getProjectContainer();
    List<Project> projects = getPopulatedProjectList(arr2);
    return projects;
}
```

But I am getting an nullpointerexception in "List projects=pc.getProject();" of test method. Can anybody help me out in this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: provide stack trace. Did you debug it? Is `pc` null or is the NPE from a within `getProject`?

Comment: I'd vote -1 for the misleading statement about where the NPE occurred.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the instance of `request` that is expected by the mock does not match the instance that is actually passed. Therefore the condition doesn't match and the mock is returning `null`.

Use

```
 when(mock.getResponse(
      Mockito.isA(GetAuthorizedWebSendTransferProjects.class)))
      .thenReturn(...)
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you. Exactly i am getting the npe as you have specified. Still what kind of configuration I need to do. Sorry for asking this silly question. I am very much new to unit testing and mocking.

Comment: Use the 'isA' as I put in my post.

Comment: You should mark the question as answered so other people don't spend time on it thinking that you have not gotten the answer you need.